# Prevent auto change row on enter key pressed in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

I've a DataGrid in WPF looks as the following:

[image: DataGrod rows]

The DataGrid's rows above, represents the following sample model:

```
    class MyModel
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to prevent the auto selection changing when i press enter key after editing the textbox, So instead of moving to the second row when editing the first row textbox content, the label on the right will be updated after some conditions ex: Text ok if text contains only digits chars, and error otherwise.

#### how can i do this?

I tried doing this by playing with the code behind of my view KeyPressed, PreviewKeyDown and LostFocus events as the following but it doesn't work :(

```
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        var dataGrid = (DataGrid) sender;
        if (dataGrid != null)
        {
            var row = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dataGrid.SelectedItem) as DataGridRow;
            base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
            //e.Handled = true;
            if (row != null)
                dataGrid.SelectedItem = row.Item;
        }
    else
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this change.

```
//base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: This prevent the auto-move to the next row, and also prevent the label on the right to be updated,